# how to keep the checkbox as selected after submitting the form in magento

Tags: template, forms

I have created a form and submitted to a controller action, the checkbox values are posted to controller, there is fine working.

But after submitting the form i cannot see the tick in  checkbox which is selected .

Below is the code

```
<div class="entry-edit">
    <form id="notification" name="notification" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getUploadUrl()?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">        
        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->getFormKey()?>" />
        <fieldset id="my-fieldset">
        <div style="float:left">
            <h1>Notification Setting</h1>
        </div>
            <table class="form-list">

                <tr>
                    <td style="float:left;padding:20px;"><input type="checkbox" name="new-lot" <?php if(isset($_POST['new-lot'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> >&nbsp;Notify Me When new lot is imported</input></td>

                    <td style="float:left;padding:20px;"><input type="checkbox" name="remark-added" <?php if(isset($_POST['remark-added'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>&nbsp;Notify Me When any new remark added </input></td>                 
                    <td style="float:left;padding:20px;">
                        <button type="submit" class="scalable save" title="Notificatiom">
                            <span>
                                <span>
                                    <span><?php echo $this->__('Submit')?></span>                                   
                                </span>
                            </span> 
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to get the data from backend whenever the user refreshes the page.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at how Magento deals with this sort of scenario. Looking at registration, `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml` , we will see the newsletter check box has the following code:

```
<?php if($this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?>
```

So what is this actually doing. Well first `getFormData` will return the attribute 'form_data' from the block, if this is not set then it will load the form data from the session via `getCustomerFormData`.

The only thing that really happens here is that when are error happens in the action, it takes the post variables and set this in the session before it redirects the user back to the page.

```
$session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
```

I would suggest that doing something similar in your code would solve your issue.